# strtotime and date returning incorrect date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here but when I convert from a date string to strtotime & back to a better formatted date string, the date is wrong:

`2015-03-20T20:00:00-0600 | Saturday Mar 21, 2015 02 00:am`

On the left is the input variable & on the right is the output of the following code:

```
  <?php
    $eventDate = '2015-03-20T20:00:00-0600';
    $originalTime = $eventDate;
    $eventDate = date('l M j, Y h i:a', strtotime($eventDate));
  ?>
  Date: <?php echo $originalTime;?> | <?php echo $eventDate; ?>
```

The correct output should be `Friday March 20th, 2015 8:00pm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually correct. The -0600 part says that your input string is 6 hours earlier than the system time, so PHP adds 6 hours which gives you `Mar 21, 2015 02 00:am`.

To get the right date and time, use the `date_default_timezone_set()` function. For me that would be:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
```

This should convert the time from UTC to your local time. If that doesn't work for you, you can always use `strstr()`:

```
$eventDate = strstr($eventDate, '+', true);
if ($eventDate === false) {
    $eventDate = $originalTime;
}
```

Comment: Oh ok, how would I override that? (I can't change the date string and everyone of them has the -0600 for some reason, i'm not sure why.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your default timezone.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

date_default_timezone_set ( string $timezone_identifier )

I'm not sure what timezone your server is configured with, but try this:

```
<?php
    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $eventDate = '2015-03-20T20:00:00+0000';
    $originalTime = $eventDate;
    $eventDate = date('l M j, Y h i:a', strtotime($eventDate));
  ?>
  Date: <?php echo $originalTime;?> | <?php echo $eventDate; ?>
```

As a sidenote, I changed the timezone offset from -0600 to +0000

That said, until you set the default timezone or correct the timezone offset in $eventDate, the date that you're trying to set (with the -0600 locale) is automatically being adapted to the local time for your server.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the newer [\DateTime API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php). Also set your default timezone appropriately. You can leave off the timezone argument below in most cases. I kept it to show how it's done when necessary.

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone("America/New_York");
$eventDate = new DateTime('2015-03-20T20:00:00-0600', $timezone);
echo $eventDate->format('l M j, Y h i:a') . "\n";
```